# Change Google Maps Icon Marker Hue Color with Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: BitmapDescriptorFactory is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have checked all corners of the internet for this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: BitmapDescriptorFactory is not defined". The closest site I could find is someone with the exact same issue with no answers. See [here](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/1171407/how-to-i-change-the-default-marker-color-in-google-maps-api-v3-via-bitmapdescriptorfactory-ask-question.html).

There are plenty of examples creating the marker with the BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE) example but I am not creating my marker the same way.

Here is what my code looks like that produces the above error.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.09342894,-36.9823909),
  map: map,
  visible: true,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  //icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
  icon: BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE),
});
```

I know i can use the commented out line but I want the default google icon as the png images are not as good quality.

Could anyone guide me how to accomplish this in the method I am using or how to translate this method to a working one?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this on web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an option in javascript, the BitmapDescriptionFactory class can be used if you are developing for Android, see the guide here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_color